# How do I can set OR condition in yii2 queryParams?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2

I've this code

```
  public function actionIndex() {
    $model = new Out();
    $searchModel = new VatoutFakturOutSearch();
    if (Yii::$app->request->post('hasEditable')) {

    $userId = Yii::$app->user->id;
    $searchModel->user_id = $userId;
$searchModel->parent_id = $userId;
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize = 100;

    return $this->render('index', [
                'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                'model' => $model,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

for **actionIndex**, for showing my index page.
with code above it will show data which has `user_id==$userId` **AND** `parent_id==$userId`.

But that's not what I need, what I need is the page show data which has `user_id==$userId` **OR** `parent_id==$userId`.

How do I can do that?

#### How do I can set OR condition in `queryParams`?

Thanks

Comment: You can manipulate $dataProvider this way:  $dataProvider->query->where(...);

Comment: @Masiorama can you give me more code example?

Comment: The two answers already contain more useful infos ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `search()` method just simply add `andWhere()` condition:

```
$query->andWhere(['or',
        ['user_id' => $this->user_id],
        ['parent_id' => $this->user_id],
]);
```

Or in controller:

```
$dataProvider->query->andWhere(['or',
        ['user_id' => $userId],
        ['parent_id' => $userId],
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use where with or operator

```
$dataProvider->query->andWhere(['or',
       ['user_id'=>$user_id],
       ['parent_id'=>$user_id]
   ]);
```